# How to Run Queries Under Rest Endpoint S7

Tags: marketing-cloud, soql, query, rest

A Company that I'm working now has a Marketing Cloud SF and we need to retrieve data from SalesForce to correlate with all other data's company.

Being more specific, we need to retrieve everyday a report about an e-mail campaign to know which costumer opened these e-mail and what time was it.

So, we'd like to run a query (SOQL) under a Rest endpoint called `/service/data` ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm)). But unfortunately, the endpoint `/services` as described on the documentation doesn't work, or doesn't even exists.

I've been trying theses hosts below but none seem to work.

```
"url": "https://restapi.s7.exacttarget.com"
"url": "https://auth.exacttargetapis.com"
"url": "https://www.exacttargetapis.com"
```

Comment: Just in case, everytime I run a GET under a /services/data/ I receive a "Service Not Found" as example below.

Leonardos-MacBook-Pro:~ leonardo$ curl https://www.exacttargetapis.com/services/data
<h1>596 Service Not Found</h1>

Comment: You should [edit] that comment into your question. One of the most useful things you can add to a question is replicable code that produces the issue in question, or the exact error text.

Comment: What you are trying to do (SOQL) is based on Force.com REST and not SFMC REST - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm

Comment: Are there other way to retrieve a simple email campaign report about how many costumers viewed these e-mail and the time these e-mail was opened?

Via REST, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not at all what you want to hear, but what you are trying to do is a Force.com REST call and not a SFMC REST call.  SFMC REST is very limited in what it can do, which unfortunately means you need to use [SOAP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieve_the_tracking_information_from_a_send.htm) and not REST to pull tracking and reporting data.

**[Which API to use?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm)**

**Use the REST API for this functionality:**

- Contacts
- Journey Builder
- Mobile Connect
- MobilePush
- Campaigns
- Triggered Sends (may also use SOAP)

**Use the SOAP API for this functionality:**

- Tracking
- Subscribers and lists
- Programs
- Triggered sends (may also use REST)
- Content
- Most other email activities

A sample in PHP on how to pull tracking info based on JobID via SOAP API:

```
<?php
require('exacttarget_soap_client.php');
$wsdl = 'https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl';
try   {
        /* Create the Soap Client */
        $client = new Marketing CloudSoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));

        /* Set username and password here */
        $client->username = 'XXX';
        $client->password = 'XXX';

        $rr = new Marketing Cloud_RetrieveRequest();
        $rr->ObjectType = "Send";   // Example DE is the name of the data extension
        $rr->Properties =  array();
            $rr->Properties[] = "ID";
        $rr->Properties[] = "SentDate";
        $rr->Properties[] = "UniqueOpens";       
        $rr->Properties[] = "NumberSent";
        $rr->Properties[] = "NumberDelivered";
            $rr->Properties[] = "HardBounces";
            $rr->Properties[] = "SoftBounces";

            // Setup a simple filter based on the key column you want to match on
        $sfp= new Marketing Cloud_SimpleFilterPart();
        $sfp->Value =  array("12345");
        $sfp->SimpleOperator = Marketing Cloud_SimpleOperators::equals;
        $sfp->Property="ID";

        $rr->Filter = new SoapVar($sfp, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'SimpleFilterPart', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI");
        $rr->Options = NULL;
        $rrm = new Marketing Cloud_RetrieveRequestMsg();
        $rrm->RetrieveRequest = $rr;       
        $results = $client->Retrieve($rrm); 
            var_dump($results);

            /* Output The Results */
            print('ID: '.$results->Results->ID.'<br>');
            print('Sent Date: '.$results->Results->SentDate.'<br>');
            print('NumberSent: '.$results->Results->NumberSent.'<br>');      

} catch (Exception  $e) {
      var_dump($e);
}
?>
```